# want to open gmap in android on clicking a button

Tags: android

I am new in android developing...I have created a project on android in which the menu page will have four image buttons...by clicking on one of these buttons i can open google maps.the other three buttons are working properly but the button which will take me googlemaps is not working.as soon as i click on that button  the application forcefully closes with the message application stopped unexpectedly. my java page is here

```
   package com.drugindexx.demo;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.drugindexx.others.Prefs;

public class MenuOptions extends Activity{

private ImageButton ibtnIndex,ibtnSearch,ibtnProfile,ibtnSettings;
private String selectedbackground;
RelativeLayout rltv_main;
RelativeLayout rltv_header;
String user;
Button btn_logout;
TextView tv_name;
String Firstname;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    rltv_header = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RLHeader);
    rltv_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RLMain);
    ibtnIndex=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnDoctor);
    ibtnSearch=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnGmap);
    ibtnProfile=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnProfile);
    ibtnSettings=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnSetting);
     btn_logout= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
     tv_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvw_name);

     LoadPreferences();
    /*if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("user") == null){
        user="";
    }
    else{
        user= getIntent().getExtras().getString("user");
    }

    if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("fname")== null){
        Firstname= "";
    }
    else{
        Firstname= getIntent().getExtras().getString("fname");

    }*/

     if(getIntent().getStringExtra("user") != null){
            user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");

     }  
            if(getIntent().getStringExtra("fname") != null){
               Firstname = getIntent().getStringExtra("fname");
               tv_name.setText(Firstname);
            } 


    ibtnSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SavePreferences("username", user);
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
     //ibtnSearch=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnGmap);
    ibtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SavePreferences("username", user);
            startActivity(new Intent(MenuOptions.this,G.class));
            //startActivity(i);
        }
    });

   ibtnProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SavePreferences("username", user);
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDetails.class);
         i.putExtra("user", user);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
  ibtnIndex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SavePreferences("username", user);
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SarchIndx.class);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
  btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SavePreferences("username", user);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("phn_no", "");
        strSavedMem1= "";
        String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "");
        strSavedMem2= "";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("phn_no"); 
        editor.remove("text");

        editor.remove("MEM1");
        editor.remove("MEM2");
        editor.commit();

        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginPage.class); 
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Prefs pref = new Prefs(MenuOptions.this);
    selectedbackground = pref.getbackground();
    setbackgroundtothisscreen();

}
private void setbackgroundtothisscreen() {
    if (selectedbackground.contains("Red")) {
        rltv_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red);
        rltv_header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.topbar_red);

    } else if (selectedbackground.contains("Blue")) {
        rltv_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_blue);
        rltv_header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.topbar_blue);


    } else if (selectedbackground.contains("Green")) {
        rltv_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_green);
        rltv_header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.topbar_green);

    }

}

protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();    

    }
private void LoadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    user = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");



    }
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

and this the xml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RLMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/midbg" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar_red" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_topbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtvw_topbar" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blankblack"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       />
  </RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLBody"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLHeader" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rltv_mainrltv" >
          <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rltv_dtlshldr"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/rl01"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




                  <ImageButton
                      android:id="@+id/imgbtnDoctor"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:src="@drawable/doctor" />

                  <ImageButton
                      android:id="@+id/imgbtnGmap"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:src="@drawable/gmap" />

              </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout 
                  android:id="@+id/rl02"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/rl01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                  >



 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtnProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtnSetting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:src="@drawable/setting" />

              </RelativeLayout>
          </RelativeLayout>
     </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

the .java page for map is:

```
  package com.drugindexx.demo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class G extends MapActivity{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.g);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
  }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}
```

the xml page for map is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/map"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="0VSKb6B9mzGfO7Ic6cKeMOZSh-8hJYOd7a4YZ3A"
             android:clickable="true"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

now i m giving the errors here::

```
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.drugindexx.demo.G
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.drugindexx.demo.MenuOptions$2.onClick     (MenuOptions.java:84)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref       in  pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-02 19:23:36.111: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  ... 12 more
```

this is it sir...trying very hard but could not correct my error...i am new in programming..looking for your help

Comment: If you have added the maps jar file in the libs folder remove it..or you may have added jar file twice

Comment: Remove the manually added maps.jar then set build target to Google APIs x.x instead of Android x.x

Comment: @Pragnani...thanks for ur rply...i hv tried but the same problem persists

Comment: @Pragnani...thanks a lot .... got isnspired to see ur "about me" in ur profile...i m also new and learning widout the aid of anyone..u inspired me a lot...nxt tym will alws search fr ur answers..keep it up